# Game Maker Multiple variable error

Tags: runtime-error, fatal-error, game-maker

My code is designed to rename a jpeg and capitalize the attributes in order to trick my Nintendo 3DS into thinking it took the image as a photo this code down here is the converter ran on a pc to convert an image to the right type and name.

```
Prefix = "HNI_";
Midfex = floor(random(9999));
Suffex = ".JPG";

gt_file=get_open_filename("jpeg image|*.jpg", "");

file_rename(gt_file, Prefix + Midfex + Suffex);
```

Where "Midfex" is, a random number with four digits is created.
and "Prefix" and "Suffex" are, they just what they are called and supposed to do.

When running the game, I get this error:

```
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of Mouse Event for Left Pressed
for object object0:

DoAdd :: Execution Error
at gml_Object_object0_LeftButtonPressed_1 (line 10) - file_rename(gt_file,Prefix + Midfex + Suffex)
```

There are probably too many variables in the "Rename_File" function. I have tried this on GameMaker 8.0 and it still does not work.  How can I fix this?

I am using the standard version of GameMaker Studio, not the free version. I have attached a screenshot of my code in Gm:s [Drive.Google.com/file/0b...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19YDO3uT0ClU202WEhhNVdMbUk/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `+` you are trying to add the number `Midfex` to `Prefix` and `Suffix`. Changing it to `Prefix + string(Midfex) + Suffex` should solve your issue as it is now in a string format.

Also for your convenience you can use `irandom(9999)` instead of `floor(random(9999))` to achieve the same result for `Midfex`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use + between string and real.

```
Prefix = "HNI_";
Midfex = string(irandom(9999));
Suffex = ".JPG";
```

or

```
file_rename(gt_file, Prefix + string(Midfex) + Suffex);
```